# scrollViewDidScroll called, but table not moving

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

Somewhere in my code I must be doing something strange. I have a UITableView with `userInteractionEnabled == true` and `scrollEnabled == true`. The table's delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll` *is* getting called when I scroll. But the UI isn't showing any table movement whatsoever. Not only is the delegate method getting called, but a pull to refresh works. I just don't see the table's cells move when I pull to refresh at all. How is this possible? If the scroll has been registered by the delegate, under what circumstances would the UI not be updated?

Comment: Try NSLog the positions the viewDidScroll delegate method throws. Maybe somewhere else in your code you're forcing the table's scroll position. If that is the case, then the delegate method will stay on the x/y position every time it gets called. This sometimes happens when you have background threads running that might alter the table's properties and halt all propagation.

Comment: @User2910293 - Logging the position at the end of viewDidScroll shows that the table IS scrolling because the values change as I scroll. I just don't see the table move at all. I think you're right then, that something else must be hijacking the position after viewDidScroll gets called.

Comment: Maybe you have something running on the main-thread that blocks all animation from happening? Finally it might be something with delegations if you manage them manually. If you didn't unbind them properly on an earlier entry in the view they might be getting in each other's way. Just random thoughts tho. Hope you'll find it!

Comment: try checking you subviews hierarchy with UI debugger